# How to fix include_once issues in my code?

Tags: php, html

I'm still new to PHP, and i've already tried several solutions but i seem to miss a point here.
I have 2 warnings, and 1 fatal error. I'm more interested in the 2 warnings, but any help is welcomed.

( ! ) Warning: include_once(model/register/register_member.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in C:\wamp\www\controller\register\index.php on line 3

( ! ) Warning: include_once(): Failed opening 'model/register/register_member.php' for inclusion (include_path='.;C:\php\pear') in C:\wamp\www\controller\register\index.php on line 3
( ! ) Fatal error: Call to a member function prepare() on a non-object in C:\wamp\www\controller\register\index.php on line 20

My 5 files : (Which all are in C:\wamp\www)

**model/register/register_member.php**

```
function register_member($pseudo, $pass_hache, $email) {
 
    global $db;
    $req = $db->prepare('INSERT INTO membres(pseudo, password, email, date_inscription) VALUES(:pseudo, :password, :email, CURDATE())');
    $req->execute(array(
        'pseudo' => $pseudo,
        'email' => $email));
    $req->closeCursor();
        'password' => $pass_hache,
}
```

**controller/register/index.php**

```
<?php
 
include_once('model/register/register_member.php');
 
if(isset($_POST['inscription'])) {
 
 
    // On rend inoffensif les données de l'utilisateur
    $_POST['pseudo'] = htmlspecialchars($_POST['pseudo']);
    $_POST['password'] = htmlspecialchars($_POST['password']);
    $_POST['password2'] = htmlspecialchars($_POST['password2']);
    $_POST['email'] = htmlspecialchars($_POST['email']);
 
 
    /**
     * Vérification si le pseudo est disponible
     */
 
    global $db;
    $req = $db->prepare('SELECT pseudo FROM membres WHERE pseudo = ?');
    $req->execute(array($_POST['pseudo']));
 
    $resultat = $req->fetch();
 
    if (!$resultat) {
        $pseudo = $_POST['pseudo'];
    } else {
        include_once('view/register/unavaipseudo.php');
    }
 
 
    /**
     * Vérification de la validité de l'adresse mail
     */
    if (isset($_POST['email'])) {
        $_POST['email'] = htmlspecialchars($_POST['email']); // On rend inoffensives les balises HTML que le visiteur a pu rentrer
 
        if (preg_match("#^[a-z0-9._-]+@[a-z0-9._-]{2,}\.[a-z]{2,4}$#", $_POST['email'])) {
            $email = $_POST['email'];
        } else {
            //echo 'L\'adresse ' . $_POST['mail'] . ' n\'est pas valide, recommencez !';
            //header('Location: mypage.php');
            include_once('view/register/wrongmail.php');
        }
    }
 
    /**
     * Vérification si le mdp est correct
     */
    if (!($_POST['password'] == $_POST['password2']))
        include_once('view/register/wrongpass.php');
 
    /**
     * Hachage du mot de passe
     */
    $pass_hache = sha1($_POST['password']);
 
    $pseudo = $_POST['pseudo'];
    $email = $_POST['email'];
 
    register_member($pseudo, $pass_hache, $email);
 
    echo 'Vous avez été inscrits !';
}
else
{
    include_once('view/register/index.php');
}
```

**view/register/index.php**

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
 
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
 
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
        <title>Inscription</title>
    </head>
    <style>
        form
        {
            text-align:center;
        }
    </style>
      
    <body>
        <h3>Inscrition à l'espace membre.</h3>
 
        <form action="controller/register/index.php" method="post">
                <p><label for="pseudo">Pseudo :</label> <input type="text" id="pseudo" name="pseudo" /></p>
                <p><label for="pass">Mot de passe : </label> <input type="password" id="pass" name="password" /></p>
                <p><label for="verif_pass">Retapez votre mot de passe : </label> <input type="password" id="password2" name="password2" /></p>
                <p><label for="email">Adresse email :</label> <input type="text" id="email" name="email" /></p>
                  
                <input type="submit" value="Inscription" name="inscription" />
        </form>
    </body>
</html>
```

**register.php (in root)**

```
<?php
 
include_once('model/connexion_ident_conn.php');
include_once('controller/register/index.php');
 
 
/*if (!isset($_GET['section']) OR $_GET['section'] == 'index')
{
    include_once('controller/register/index.php');
}*/
```

And of course, a file to connect to the DB (**model/connexion_ident_conn.php**).
I know that the quality of my code is really bad, i'm going to rewrite everything in OOP. But i'm really interested in what i'm missing now.

Comment: First thing, you should setup your autoloading mechanism when going for an MVC pattern.

Comment: Found the solution : include_once('/../../model/register/register_member.php');

What do you mean by autoloading mechanism ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your file is inside 
`controller/register/index.php`

and you include
`include_once('model/register/register_member.php');`

Probably your not including the file from your `web-root` here. Try it with a leading slash:
`include_once('/model/register/register_member.php');` 
Or you have to go back in your file structure:
`include_once('/../../model/register/register_member.php');`

To Alex Linte's Comment:

`Autoload` means that every Class you use, is automatically included. 
Take a look on how to implement it, here:
http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.autoload.php

Answer (score 0):

Your 2 Warnings are mistakes with your paths!

So insteat of this:

```
include_once('model/register/register_member.php');
```

it should be:

```
include_once('/../../model/register/register_member.php');
```

And your error has todo with your `$db` variable which is not a object!